# Aumento el rendimiento en Canvas

Tags: canvas

Si necesito dibujar muchísimas imágenes en canvas

Es factible usar

```
canvas.imageSmoothingQuality = "low";
```

Para mejorar el rendimiento? EN LA MDN, no dice nada acerca del rendimiento con este método